# Fingerprint authetication of multiple users

Tags: android, database, authentication, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am a beginner in android development.I want to create an application having Finger authentication.I want to register multiple users(50) finger prints using finger sensor of phone.Also i want to authenticate it when user logins.Can anyone help us?

Comment: U have no permission to get the finger print details from finger sensor of phone.U can only get the authentication of the saved user, no extra information

Comment: I want to make attendance app.when employees login with fingerprint the app should show a success message.How can i do it?

Comment: Is it possible to register multiple users using fingerprint sensors in marshmallow phones?

Comment: If user using the different phone we can do that ,While authenticate the u have to give the server a unique id , if this user login  u can track the user by this id

Comment: I have to implement this in one phone.in same app i have to register multiple users?

Comment: @Mariya were you able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

FingeprintManager only has these 3 features:

authenticate : for authenticating user

hasEnrolledFingerprints : Determine if there is at least one fingerprint enrolled.

isHardwareDetected : Determine if fingerprint hardware is present and functional.

you can check FingerPrintManager docs here : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html

Answer (score 0):

As per [Nexus FAQs](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6300638?hl=en)

> Your fingerprint data is stored securely and never leaves your Pixel
>   or Nexus phone. Your fingerprint data isn't shared with Google or any
>   apps on your device. Apps are notified only whether your fingerprint
>   was verified.

which explains very well that you can use fingerprints for verification purpose only. Its just an alternative to any app lock available in marketplace.